# Question about classification with hidden Markov models using depmixS4

Tags: time-series, classification, hidden-markov-model

I am using the depmixS4 package to fit HMMs.

I have three different classes of data and I have fitted 3 separate HMMs using the depmixS4 depmix and fit functions and given a new sequence of observations, I would like to be able to compute the probability (or log odds) of that new observation sequence given each of the three models that have already been trained.

I understand this would normally be done using the Viterbi algorithm, but I have no idea how this can be implemented in depmixS4.

Due to the functionality of depmixS4 I cannot use the HMM or HiddenMarkov packages

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance

Comment: If the package is able to fit an HMM then has to be computing the probability of sequences given a model, so it's got to be in there somewhere. And the Viterbi algorithm is not what you want; that computes the most likely state path. All you need is the probability of a sequence given a model, which only requires some multiplication and summation.

Answer (score 0):

You must use ***forward*** function to calculate the likelihood by sum forward's probability from first step until last one.

```
sum(forward_prob(t))
```